# segmenting datas at pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem with segmenting a pd.DataFrame (or pd.Series) at a point the value switches.

For example, I have a data like

```
list('AAAAABBBBBAAABBBCCCCBBBBAAAAA')
```

as you can see, As and Bs and Cs are arranged in chunks.

What is the most pythonic way to manage them in to segments?

I believe the code will be produce a array-like data that is like:

```
list('00000111112223334445555666677777')
```

which is a list of the names for the segments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most pythonic way would be using [itertools.groupby()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

But your output format needs some work as it only holds 10 numbers (0-9) what's the difference between character '11' and '1' when it's repeated several times like that.

Comment: thanks a lot! my output format was just to avoid the lousy [0,0,0,0,1, ... ] which  could have been veeery long.